# Local systems and locally free sheaves in families

Tags: complex-geometry, deformation-theory

Let $X_{t}$ be a family of compact complex manifolds over the disk $\mathbb{D}\subset \mathbb{C}.$  Formally, $X_{t}$ is the fiber over $t\in\mathbb{D}$ of a proper, holomorphic submersion of a complex manifold $\mathcal{X}$ onto $\mathbb{D}.$  Suppose $E_{t}$ is a family of holomorphic vector bundles over $X_{t}$ equipped with a family of holomorphic flat connections $\nabla^{t}.$

If $\mathbb{V}_{t}$ denotes the local system prescribed by $\nabla^{t},$ we have the inclusion of sheaves $0\rightarrow \mathbb{V}_{t}\rightarrow \mathcal{E}_{t}$ where $\mathcal{E}_{t}$ is the sheaf of germs of holomorphic sections of $E_{t}.$

Suppose that for all $t\neq 0$ in the disk, the induced map
$H^{1}(X_{t}, \mathbb{V}_{t})\rightarrow H^{1}(X_{t}, \mathcal{E}_{t})$ is an isomorphism.

Question:  Does it follow that the induced map over zero $H^{1}(X_{0}, \mathbb{V}_{0})\rightarrow H^{1}(X_{0}, \mathcal{E}_{0})$ 
is an isomorphism?

If it makes life any better, I am happy to assume that the dimension of $H^{1}(X_{t}, \mathbb{V}_{t})$ is constant over all of $\mathbb{D}.$

I suspect the answer is no, but haven't unearthed a counterexample as of yet.
Thank you for any insight you can provide.

Comment: One can come up with counterexamples where you actually have an isomonodromic deformation, but that seems to be more than what you are asking. We can take X_t to be an elliptic curve (independent of t), and E_t to be a line bundle. Then we have the following cases: 1. E_t is not trivial: both cohomology groups are zero; 2. E_t is trivial, but connection is not: first cohomology group is zero, second is one-dimensional 3. E_t and connection are both trivial: first cohomology group is two-dimensional, second is one-dimensional. So your map is an isomorphism in case 1, but not in cases 2 and 3...

Comment: so can just take a family of line bundles on your elliptic curve that is trivial for t=0 and non-trivial for t\ne 0.